# @media query is not working with main style sheet, linking to it as an external sheet works

Tags: html, css, media-queries, stylesheet

I'm trying to condense my external css media query style sheet and my main css stylesheet.

When I link to the external style sheet, the media query works properly.. but after I tried to add the code to my main css stylesheet, it no longer works.

I've been looking at a tutorial and downloaded some files, but I'm still stumped.

I linked to my external media query css sheet by linking it like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 2500px)' href='css/r_700.css' />
```

This worked fine.

Here is the header I have for my page at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Responsive Tester Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' media='all' />

    <!--   
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 2500px)' href='css/r_700.css' />
     -->

</head>
```

Here is the code in the external r_700 style sheet:

```
body {
    background-color:#00F;
    background-image:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
```

Here is the code in the main style.css sheet (that I can't get to work):

```
@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color:#00F;
            background-image:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            }
    }
```

The @media is the very last bit of lines in the main stylesheet, so I know nothing is writing over it.

I know it has to be something simple, like screwed up syntax or something like that. I feel really dumb that I can't get this silly thing to work.

Does anyone mind helping me out? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that your baseline styles and your media query both contain the same definition. Maybe that's why you don't see it change? Working for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kr8kcd8y/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the code that you are replacing in your media query is **the exact same** as the code in your default CSS:

Default:

```
body {
background-color:#00F;
background-image:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

vs:

```
@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        background-color:#00F;
        background-image:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        }
}
```

You're not changing anything, so the page looks the same...

Comment: Ah jeez, can't believe I forgot to change the bg color. Thanks lol. I changed it, but it still wasn't working.. I did find what was causing it to not work though... I had to take out this, which was just before the code: <!-- Media Queries for Responsive Site --> I screwed up the commenting out code and used <!-- --> instead of /*  */